# 803 facebook error

Tags: php, facebook

I have an application on facebook that has worked for a month, but now I get the page in the application blank to enter it.

The application using the debugger get the error 803:
"Error":
"Message": "(# 803) Some of the aliases you do not exist Requested: bloggsamigos"
"Type": "OAuthException"
"Code": 803

If acceds directly see the message "the application is blocked because of problems with an external programmer."

What confuses me is that it has worked perfectly and I have not touched anything.

The application shows some pictures coming out of a query to a database hosted on the same domain. It's a blog of images. I have an administrator outside of facebook online application and show these images run from the administrator.

in index.php page, I control the user has the "like" activated to display a page or other. my code is this:

---

```
require 'src/facebook.php';
$config = array();
$config['appId'] ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$config['secret'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
$encoded_sig = null;
$payload = null;
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
$sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
$signed_request = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true),true); 
} else { echo "ERROR"; }
$lied = $signed_request['page']['liked'];
if ($signed_request['page']['liked']) {
include("fan.php");
}
else {
include("nofan.php");
}
```

---

configuration data are:
Namespace App --> bloggsamigos

Site URL -->  with (http://www) mahesoblogsamigos.com/

Site Domain --> with (http://www) mahesoblogsamigos.com

Work Page --> with (http://) apps.facebook.com/bloggsamigos/

URL of the canvas -->  with (https://)  ssl15.ovh.net/~mahesobl/

Secure URL Canvas --> with (https://)  ssl15.ovh.net/~mahesobl/

Canvas FBML / iframe --> iframe

I'm desperate, I tried many things, I wanted information, I sent emails to facebook, but I can not help. You can help me, please! I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the namespace to something else...

http://graph.facebook.com/bloggsamigos shows:  "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: bloggsamigos" meaning that facebook is not able to figure out what application that namespace matches with.  Chances are something got messed up on Facebook's side.

If you really want that namespace, you may be able to change it to something else and then change it back to that to hopefully get it to record the information correctly.

You can also try filing a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs but don't be surprised if you have to wait for weeks or months for a response.

Going to http://apps.facebook.com/bloggsamigos/ also shows a message saying "The app "Bloggs Amigos" is temporarily unavailable due to an issue with its third-party developer. We are investigating the situation and apologize for any inconvenience."  However, that could mean almost anything.

Comment: thanks for your help @TimTisdal.

I tried to change the namespace, but there is no change ... immediately. I Don't know if I have to be patient and wait a few hours or just does not work. It is possible that someone has reported that Facebook has blocked the application. The strange thing is that I even bought another domain, I installed everything again and with another name, another domain, another namespace, another ssl access .... does not work, I get the same text as that application is bloquedada:

http://apps.facebook.com/mbloggsamigos

Any more ideas?

Comment: very strange...  definitely file a bug at  http://developers.facebook.com/bugs but you could try fiddling with other settings.
It sounds like they've added some sort of restriction on your account.  Does it say anything when you look at the apps settings at https://developers.facebook.com/apps ?